# Why does `inputs` skip the first line of the input file?

Tags: json, csv, jq

Whenever I provide a file to jq and use the `inputs` command, I only get back all lines but the first one and I'm wondering why is that

I'm currently using jq 1.6 and I'm trying to use the `inputs` command to convert a TSV (Tab Separated Values) into JSON by grabbing the first line of the file as the headers and placing each header as the key of the corresponding value in the next lines

If I execute the following

```sh
echo -n 'line1'$'\n''line2' | jq -R 'inputs'
```

The result is

```
line2
```

and not

```
line1
line2
```

as I'd expect

As a workaround I'm currently prepending a new line to the input i'm giving to jq as in

```
echo -n $'\n''line1'$'\n''line2' | jq -R 'inputs'
```

but my expectation is to be able to use `inputs` and have it process the first line

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`jq` itself is reading the first line, then `inputs` (having received that line as *its* input) will read the rest. Typically, you want to use the `-n` option to prevent `jq` from doing any reading itself, letting any `input` or `inputs` filters do the actual reading.

```
$ echo -n $'line1\nline2\n' | jq -nR 'inputs'
"line1"
"line2"
```

In your case, letting `jq` read the header and `inputs` read the rest of the data is reasonable, but you have to *do* something with the header. This is probably more complicated than it needs to be, but does the job:

```
$ cat tmp.tsv
foo bar baz
1   2   3
4   5   6
$ jq -R 'split("\t") as $h | [inputs | split("\t") | [{key: $h[0], value: .[0]}, {key: $h[1], value: .[1]}, {key: $h[2], value: .[2]}] | from_entries]' tmp.tsv
[
  {
    "foo": "1",
    "bar": "2",
    "baz": "3"
  },
  {
    "foo": "4",
    "bar": "5",
    "baz": "6"
  }
]
```

`jq` reads the first line and splits it into the array `h`, then feeds that line to a filter which ignores it but uses `inputs` to read the rest of the lines, splitting each one up and creating a dict using (repeatedly) the value of `$h`.

Comment: It would probably be better to encourage the use of `objectify` defined e.g. as `def objectify($h): . as $in | reduce range(0; $h|length) as $i ({}; .[$h[$i]] = $in[$i]);`

Answer (score 4):

@chepner's explanation of `-n` is fine, but I'd like to illustrate how `debug` can help clarify and/or demystify jq's behavior.

Since every jq program is a filter, it is always possible to see what the input to any given filter is by prepending it with `debug`, so e.g.:

```
echo 1 2 3 | jq 'debug | inputs'
```

yields:

```
["DEBUG:",1]
2
3
```

That is, in this case, the input to `inputs` is 1, which is consumed by `inputs` and otherwise ignored.

We can similarly examine the effect of using the `-n` command-line option:

```
echo 1 2 3 | jq -n 'debug | inputs'
["DEBUG:",null]
1
2
3
```

That is, we can now see that the `-n` option tells jq to provide `null` as the input to `inputs`, rather than obtaining it from STDIN.

In short, `debug` is helpful not only for debugging, but also for DIY understanding.